# About group algebras. Are $R(G_1\times G_2)$, $(RG_1)G_2$ isomorphic?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let be $R$ a ring conmutative whith unity and $G_1,$ $G_2$ multiplicative groups. Prove the $R(G_1\times G_2)\cong (RG_1)G_2$.

I tried prove that $r_{gh}(g,h)\mapsto (r_{gh}g)h$ is an isomorphism , but I can't the lineality of the sum.

Comment: $R[G\times H]\cong R[G]\otimes_R R[H]$, see [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=2xrSHX-rpGMC&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=group+algebra+K%5BG+x+H%5D+is+isomorphic+to+tensor+product+of+K%5BG%5D+and+K%5BH%5D&source=bl&ots=0Mrwio077p&sig=bYQJMKEyQAIKChRkUUgeiIc0OH8&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGwZDe9brQAhVFB8AKHXQuD3IQ6AEIPzAE#v=onepage&q=group%20algebra%20K%5BG%20x%20H%5D%20is%20isomorphic%20to%20tensor%20product%20of%20K%5BG%5D%20and%20K%5BH%5D&f=false).

Comment: Isn't a homomorphism defined if it is defined on generators?